# why my asp:hiddenfield is not working but my label is?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a very strange problem trying to get the value from an ASP.NET HiddenField control in a page using a master page. I have a page were I show a label and a hiddenfield control. I set the value to both controls when the user calls the page and I can see the value assigned when I view the HTML source:

This is my setup.

```
test.aspx

<asp:Label ID="lbl_total" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdn_total" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btn_test" runat="server" Text="Get Value" OnClick="btn_test_Click" />
```

In the code behind I set the value for both controls:

```
lbl_total.Text = "10";
hdn_total.Value = "10";
```

When I opens text.aspx, I can see the value correctly set in the controls:

```
<span id="panel_body_lbl_label">10</span>
<input type="hidden" name="ctl00$panel_body$hdn_total" id="panel_body_hdn_total" value="10" />
```

So far so good. The problem starts when I press the button control:

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_test" runat="server" Text="Get Value" OnClick="btn_test_Click" />
```

When I press the submit button, in the code behind I have the following:

```
protected void btn_test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
    Response.Write("hdn_total=" + hdn_total.Value);
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
       Response.Write(ex.message);
   }
}
```

and the value of hdn_total.Value is empty. I can however still get the value of lbl_total.Text

I have never seen a problem like this occur. Normally I always can get the value from a hiddenfield without any problems. I must be missing something really obvious but after two days looking at this I need some help to figure out this problem, thanks a lot.

UPDATE - Adding my .aspx.cs file below without the obvious namespaces

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message + ex.Source + ex.InnerException + ex.StackTrace);
    }
}

protected void btn_test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Response.Write("lbl_total=" + lbl_total.Text);
        Response.Write("hdn_total=" + hdn_total.Value.Trim());
        return;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { Response.Write("<!-- debug =" + ex.Message + ex.InnerException + ex.Source + ex.StackTrace + "-->"); }
}

protected void grdTest_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ShoppingCart.Instance.Items == null)
    {
        cart_footer.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (grdCart.Items.Count() == 0)
        { return; }

        string price_format = SiteConfiguration.configValue("price_format");
        string total = String.Format(price_format, ShoppingCart.Instance.GetSubTotal());

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(total))
        {
            lbl_total.Text = total;
            hdn_total.Value = Convert.ToString(ShoppingCart.Instance.GetSubTotal());
        }
        else
        {
            cart_footer.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I am using a listview on the test.aspx page BUT my lbl_total and hdn_total controls are outside the listview so that shouldn't make any difference. I set the value to both controls on my OnDataBound because I retrieve the values from the listview. I do get the values correctly for both controls when I access the test.aspx file as I can see them when I view the HTML source code in the browser. The problem is when I click on the submit button, it supposed to read both controls values, that's all but I only get the value for the lbl_test and not the hdn_test and that's what is very strange.

Comment: Can you upload your aspx.cs. It's most likely the hidden field is altered in postback event

Comment: Alternatively you can put the value in ViewState which should persist across postbacks.  Something like: ViewState["hdn_total"] = "10";

Comment: hi @Greg thanks for stepping in. I just uploaded the aspx.cs file thanks a lot for also sharing your thoughts

Comment: If you put a break point on grdTest_DataBound. Does this get called before btn_test_Click?

Comment: @Greg your question kept me thinking and I found the problem thanks to that, basically the grd_Test_DataBound was called, thank you so much for helping open my eyes. I spend two days on this and I clearly the error was in front of my eyes but I could not see it until you help me realize it, you're a star :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can put the value in ViewState which should persist across postbacks. Something like:

```
 ViewState["hdn_total"] = "10"


 //check for it
 if(ViewState["hdn_total"] != null)
 {
      //exists so put it in a variable 
      string yourval = ViewState["hdn_total"].ToString();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @JobesK for your alternative solution. I can create session variables or even cookies or just take the value from the label itself but I am still curious as to why the hiddenfield is not working for me on this situation :(.

Comment: Yes I'm curious too, where exactly are you setting the HiddenField value (what method)?  You could also try adding EnableViewState="true" on the hiddenField, it supposed to default to true but worth testing to see.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following which forces the control's **ViewState** to be enabled since by default it is inherited from the container. It does not hurt also to set the **ClientIDMode** to Static so the control ID is not mangled by ASP.NET.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdn_total" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ViewStateMode="Enabled" />
```

Another option you may want to try is put the controls in an **UpdatePanel**.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lbl_total" runat="server"></asp:Label>
         <asp:HiddenField ID="hdn_total" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ViewStateMode="Enabled" />
         <asp:Button ID="btn_test" runat="server" Text="Get Value" OnClick="btn_test_Click" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Thanks Jamal for giving me another alternative solution to the problem. @Greg helped me to find my mistake so I was able correct the problem. Nonetheless, your suggestion also works therefore, I will give it for good also as this can hopefully help others find alternative solutions, thanks so much again :)